# Pattern matching a Makefile target name

Tags: makefile

In a Makefile recipe, I can refer to the current target name by using '$@'.

Assuming you have:

```
%.foo:
  @echo "Blah!"
```

And you call that with:

```
make bar
```

'$@' would return 'bar.foo'. Is there a way to refer just to 'bar'?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `$*` to get the `%` part of the target:

```
%.foo:
    @echo $*
```